# SSRS report headers are not fixed when exported to Excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services

My SSRS report looks like this:

[image]

The rows that have a grey background are fixed headers. They need to stay on the page when you scroll. It works fine when I run it on SSRS but when I export it to Excel, it does not. I want these rows to stay fixed when exported.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is another age-old bug that **Microsoft refuses to fix** ("it works as we designed it!"). The header will repeat in all other export types **except Excel**.

The only way to make it work the way you want is copy your text boxes in the table header and paste them in the Header section of the report.

[image]

Unfortunately, you would also have to change the **Company Logo** and **Name** fields in the header to make it work after you move it into the page header.

Here's an issue for the bug that's still open in case you want to add to it:

[excel-export-create-freeze-pane-on-tablix-header-row-not-page-header-row](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/561128/excel-export-create-freeze-pane-on-tablix-header-row-not-page-header-row)

Comment: I was hoping it would not come down to that, but yeah. I am going to have to do this. I just created a header and moved the contents of the Table header to the page header. How do I set my page header properties to FixedData, KeepWithGroup, and RepeatOnNewPage? I don't see it on the properties pane.